# bootstrap 5 accordion: prevent toggle on specified elements in header

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-5, preventdefault, bootstrap-accordion

I have bootstrap 5 accordion
want to show popover to be displayed by clicking on icon in accordion header
popover is working but accordion is also toggling. I want to prevent toggling accordion if that popover-handler element is clicked.
my code is also there in https://codepen.io/fakhre-alam/pen/zYERaqQ

```
<div class="accordion-item mb-3 border shadow-sm">
            <h2 class="accordion-header" id="panelsStayOpen-headingOne">
                <button class="d-inine-block accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#panelsStayOpen-collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="panelsStayOpen-collapseOne">
                    Heading                                                                        
                    <i class="fa fa-info-circle ms-3 popover-handler no-collapsable" 
                        data-bs-trigger="click" 
                        data-html="true" 
                        data-bs-title="Title of POPOVER <i class='float-end btn-popover btn-close'></i>" 
                        data-bs-content="some text in popover<br />
                            some more text in popover<br />
                            even more text in popover<br />
                            last line of text in popover</b>">
                    </i>
                </button>
                
            </h2>
            <div id="panelsStayOpen-collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse show" aria-labelledby="panelsStayOpen-headingOne">
                <div class="accordion-body p-0 px-2" >                     
                        accordion content<br>
                        accordion content<br>
                        accordion content<br>
                        accordion content<br>
                        accordion content<br> 
                </div><!--.accordion-body-->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


<script>
$(function(){ 
    $('.popover-handler').popover({  
            html: true, 
    }); 
    $('body').on('click', '.popover-handler',function (e) {
         e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know nested elements inside `.accordion-button` will not allow logging of inner element's events. I have some suggestions for you:

**Suggestion 1:** Split `<i>` in `.accordion-button` and then  with absolute positioning achieve a visually similar appearance. Try it like this:

```
<style>
    .accordion-header {
        position: relative;
    }
    .i-custom {
        position: absolute;
        right: 50px;
        z-index: 9999;
    }
    .tooltip-custom {
        position: absolute;
        top: 15px;
        right: 10px;
        z-index: 99999;
    }
</style>
<div class="accordion-item mb-3 border shadow-sm">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="panelsStayOpen-headingOne">
        <div class="d-flex">
            <button class="d-inine-block accordion-button text-start"
                    type="button"
                    data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                    data-bs-target="#panelsStayOpen-collapseOne"
                    aria-expanded="true"
                    aria-controls="panelsStayOpen-collapseOne">
                <h5 class="content_title fw-bold w-100 text-left">Heading 1</h5>
            </button>
            <div class="d-flex align-items-start tooltip-custom">
                <i class="fa fa-info-circle ms-3 popover-handler no-collapsable i-custom"
                   data-bs-trigger="click"
                   data-html="true"
                   data-bs-title="Title of POPOVER <i class='float-end btn-popover btn-close'></i>"
                   data-bs-content="some text in popover<br />
                        some more text in popover<br />
                        even more text in popover<br />
                        last line of text in popover</b>">
                </i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </h2>
    <div id="panelsStayOpen-collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse show"
         aria-labelledby="panelsStayOpen-headingOne">
        <div class="accordion-body p-0 px-2">
            accordion content<br>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Suggestion 2:** Change from `click` to `hover` event

```
<div class="accordion-item mb-3 border shadow-sm">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="panelsStayOpen-headingTwo">
        <button class="d-inine-block accordion-button text-start"
                type="button"
                data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                data-bs-target="#panelsStayOpen-collapseTwo"
                aria-expanded="true"
                aria-controls="panelsStayOpen-collapseTwo">
            Heading 2
            <i class="fa fa-info-circle ms-3 popover-handler no-collapsable i-hover"
               data-html="true"
               data-bs-title="Hover POPOVER <i class='float-end btn-popover btn-close'></i>"
               data-bs-content="some text in popover<br />
                        last line of text in popover</b>">
            </i>
        </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="panelsStayOpen-collapseTwo" class="accordion-collapse collapse show"
         aria-labelledby="panelsStayOpen-headingOne">
        <div class="accordion-body p-0 px-2">
            accordion content<br>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $(function(){
        $('.i-hover').hover(function () {
            const popover = bootstrap.Popover.getInstance($(this))
            popover.toggle()
        })
    });
</script>
```

Full code [here](https://codepen.io/lam-td/pen/rNGdBNQ?editors=1111)

Comment: thank you @Lam, I can not go with 2nd suggession as my requirement is strictly based on click. I already did it with absolute positioning and also managed to position it right after the text ending instead of fixed right position. still hoping some one will reply with standard way of doing it.

Comment: I ran into very weird issue when there is dropdown inside the accordion-header. If i set that to position:absolute then dropdown is clipping off behind next item's accordion-button element and if i don't then clicking on dropdown is causing accordion to toggle.